# Why do I have to connect to Internet when I am using MySQL in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a strange issue when using MySQL in NodeJS. When I connect to the Internet, my MySQL database works, however, when I'm offline, querying the MySQL database gives me an error. I'm using an Express connection.

**My connection**:

```
app.use(
    connection( mysql, {
        host: dbConfig.host,
        user: dbConfig.user,
        password: dbConfig.password,
        database: dbConfig.database
    }, 'pool' )
);
```

**Error message**:

```
{
  [Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost:3306]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

And:

```
connection.query(
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're missing a `localhost` entry in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: doesn't seem, it just file contains mappings between an IP address and a name of the host.

Comment: So you *do* have an entry for `localhost` in `/etc/hosts` such as `127.0.0.1 localhost` or `::1 localhost` or similar? If you *don't*, then you should add such an entry. You might also want to check your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to ensure that `files` comes before `dns` on the `hosts:` line.

Comment: oh thanks, you make me open mind. 
I try to change configuration of the host from localhost to 127.0.0.1
that's work!
like: 

`var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.0.0.1', // no loger localhost
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database    : 'nodejs_db'
});`

and for my hosts
127.0.0.1        localhost:90